# Many self hosted SSL owin servers

Tags: iis, ssl, asp.net-web-api, owin, katana

I have a scenario where I have upwards of 100+ self hosted owin servers (webapi). I communicate with these self hosted servers from another web application hosted on IIS.

I need this communication to be over SSL. I have a couple of questions

- How do I setup SSL with a self hosted owin server?
- Can I purchase one SSL and install on the one webapp and on the 100+ self hosted servers?

Comment: netsh is the command and yes once you get the certificate you can use it that way.

Answer (score 0):

Selfhost url and ssl setup docs: http://katanaproject.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Selfhosting&referringTitle=Documentation.

SSL sertificates are for specific domains. You can get one that covers multiple domains, but those are more expensive.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can! Get one certificate for your hosting domain and you can host your individual  OWIN services under separate port numbers. You should be able to find plenty of resources on how to setup SSL with self hosted OWIN server.